# Automatically copy cell value to first empty row on edit

Tags: function, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My App Script writing is beginner level, but based on the videos that I have watched, it seems like the scripts I have tried should work. I have a Google Sheet (Sample) that is designed like a fillable form in which users can select pre-loaded selections from a dropdown or add their own (the dropdowns are based on named ranges on the "lists" sheet). Because users are very low-level tech skills, I am trying to automate it so that if they enter their own text into the dropdown instead of using the selections available in the named range/dropdown, it will automatically add their text to the last rown in the appropriate column on the lists tab so that it is automatically added to that named range and is an option the next time they use the Sample tab.

What I want is if I type "TEST" in B2 on the Sample tab, I want it to automatically add "TEST" to the first empty row in col A on the lists tab (highlighted yellow). I want this same action to apply for each dropdown I have in the sheet and where it automatically adds the entry to the corresponding named range (so an addition to sample B3 would paste to lists B4 and so on).

I tried to get the code to work just for one dropdown to start and couldn't get it to work so would also need to know how to get this to apply for each dropdown on the sample sheet (this is a smaller version as the original sheet has about 10 dropdowns in different rows/columns).

The second issue that I have is that this sheet is meant to be copied. From what research I have done, it seems that scripts need to be authorized (once again, low-level tech users who would have no clue how to do this and this would be shared outside of my agency). Is there a workaround for this? I normally would just share the sheet link as such so that it automatically copies it: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19RJI2onO8u8YYtWpztXBOdMR7UXRXugr2u5-hsvQ_44/copy

[image: Sample Sheet]

[image: Lists Sheet]

When I tried either of these scripts, nothing happened.
ATTEMPT 1 (added onEdit trigger)

```
function PasteValue(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var copySheet = ss.getSheetByName("sample");
var appendSheet = ss.getSheetByName("lists");
appendSheet.getRange(1,appendSheetPasteRow); 
copySheet.getRange("B1").copyTo(appendSheet.getRange(1,appendSheetPasteColumn),{contentsOnly:true});}
```

ATTEMPT 2

```
`function CopyRow(){
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var dataSht = ss.getSheetByName("sample");
var listSht = ss.getSheetByName ("lists");
var lastRow = listSht.getLastRow();
var dataRng = dataSht.getRange("B1").getvalues();
listSht.getRange(lastRow + 1,1,1,1).setValues(dataRng);
}
function onEdit(e){
if(e.range.getA1Notation() == "B1") {
  CopyRow();
```

Comment: Here are the scripts I tried using...kept erroring when I tried to include it in the original post:

Comment: appendPasteRow is undefined and appendSheetPasteColumn is undefined

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
function PasteValue() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var ssh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  dsh.getRange(1, 1);
  ssh.getRange("B1").copyTo(dsh.getRange(1, 1), { contentsOnly: true });
}
```

and these do also now:

```
function CopyRow() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var dsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  var lsh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var lastRow = lsh.getLastRow();
  var dv = dsh.getRange("B1").getValue();
  lsh.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1).setValue(dv);
}
function onEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.getA1Notation() == "B1") {
    CopyRow();
  }
}
```

Comment: how would I get it so it goes to the first empty cell in  Column A on the Lists sheet (guessing that's Sheet 1 in your code)? When I plugged this in, it changed the content in A1 in lists to what I had entered in B1 on the sample sheet.

Comment: it works perfectly with the CopyRow function. Thank you! Would I just add in a   var dv = dsh.getRange("B1").getValue(); for each cell that there is a DV and do the same for the onEdit function cell reference?

Comment: If you're learning the best thing to do is to try different stuff and don't worry about making mistakes.  Checkout the event object from the onEdit trigger.